# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre yield y return?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo sobre las funciones generadoras en python.

Pero me surgio esa pequeña duda de...

¿Cual es la diferencia entre yield y return?

Espero me ayuden pronto con esto :/

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `return`  en primer lugar, fuerza una salida inmediata de la función en que se encuentra. es decir, hace que la ejecución del programa vuelva al código que llamó a la función.

```
def escribe_media():
    media = (a + b) / 2
    print(f"La media de {a} y {b} es: {media}")
    return # hacer que el programa salga de la función y vuelva donde fue llamado
```

En segundo lugar. puede ser utilizado para devolver un valor

```
def suma(x, y):
    resultado = (x + y)
    return resultado #Devuelve un valor
```

---

En cuanto a `yield` (es similar a `return`) se usa en generadores (que son básicamente iteradores), es decir devuelven de a un único valor, ya que los van creando sobre la marcha:

```
def generaNumeros():
    yield numeros # devuelve un dato, entra en suspensión y se devuelve de donde
    # fue llamado
g = generaNumeros() #Generador
print(next(g))#Devuelve un solo dato
print(next(g))#Devuelve el siguiente dato
```

También existe `yield from` su función básicamente es simplificar el código de los generadores en el caso de utilizar bucles anidados, además es útil cuando se quiere obtener los subelementos que posee un elemento en concreto:

```
def devuelve_mensaje(mensaje):
    for elemento in mensaje:
        yield from elemento
```

Al momento de llamar la función

```
mensaje_devuelto = devuelve_mensaje("Hola")
```

Se obtendría:

```
print(next(mensaje_devuelto)) # Se obtendría "H"
print(next(mensaje_devuelto)) # Se obtendría "o"
```

Comment: el yield ahorra memoria porque no devuelve todo, solo lo que necesita, entonces el return los devuelve todos de golpe supongo. Verdad?

Comment: Claro, bastante útiles en listas que tienen valores infinitos, se llega hasta el elemento necesitado y ya no se usa más, por ejemplo :)