# Uso de generadores (yield) en el método de una clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

La consigna que tengo es la siguiente:

> Question: Define a class with a generator which can iterate the
> numbers, which are divisible by 7, between a given range 0 and n.
>
> Use yield

Mí dificultad radica en tener que utilizar generadores (yield), ya que en el caso de hacerlo de una forma "tradicional"no tengo ningún problema. Y más específicamente (creo yo) radica en la forma de imprimir los datos. Seguramente es algo muy básico y sin complejidad mayor, pero la verdad estoy estancado.

Este es mí código:

```
class NumberGenerator:
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max
    
    def generate(self):
        for number in range(7, self.max):
            if number % 7 == 0:
                yield number
        print(next(generate))

generacion1 = NumberGenerator(100)
generacion1.generate()
```

Sin embargo, si lo hago de una forma tradicional, no tengo problema alguno:

```
class NumberGenerator:
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max
    
    def generate(self):
        for number in range(7, self.max):
            if number % 7 == 0:
                print(number)

generacion1 = NumberGenerator(100)
generacion1.generate()
```

Es importante resaltar que, si bien resulta innecesario crear una clase, lo solicita la consigna, y por lo tanto lo tengo que hacer de esa manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi, recuerda que `yield` "devuelve" un generador. Veámoslo en la consola:

```
>>> def generate(n):
...     for number in range(7, n+1):
...         if number % 7 == 0:
...             yield number
...
>>> generacion1 = generate(25)
>>> type(generacion1)
<class 'generator'> # Devolvió un generador
>>> list(generacion1)
[7, 14, 21]
>>>
```

Básicamente tendrías que poner eso mismo en el método `generate()` y asignarle a una variable el llamado al método para obtener el generador, o convertirlo a lista.

```
class NumberGenerator:
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max
    
    def generate(self):
        for number in range(7, self.max+1):
            if number % 7 == 0:
                yield number

generacion1 = NumberGenerator(100)
print(list(generacion1.generate()))  # [7, 14, 21...]
```

Hay [buena información aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20yield) para entender mejor yield:
[¿Qué es yield en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/254318/80870)
[¿Cual es la diferencia entre yield y return?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/309104/80870)

PD. ¿Es obligatorio calcular el módulo? Mejor sale solo contar de 7 en 7 hasta el límite.

Comment: Muchas gracias.